# SQL/HiveQL: Is there a way to count the number of JOIN <table> ON <condition> matches per row without a group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hive, hiveql

I would like to do a LEFT (OUTER) JOIN on two tables and have a column in the resulting table indicate how many times a record from the right table met the JOIN ON condition of for the left table.

Consider the following tables:

```
 Students          Absences
name    ID        ID   date  
Kyle    1         1    7/04
Chris   2         2    7/04
Sam     3         2    7/20
Maura   4         1    8/01
                  3    8/02
                  1    8/02
```

I would like to create new table to show how many times a student appears in the Absences table. The resulting table would look like:

```
name     ID   absences
Kyle     1    3
Chris    2    2
Sam      3    1
Maura    4    0
```

I understand a solution could be something like:

```
SELECT Students.name, Student.ID, t1.ct as absences
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, count(*) as ct
           FROM Absences
           GROUP BY ID) t1
ON Students.ID = t1.ID
```

...but I would like to avoid using a GROUP BY in my solution because I am dealing with millions of rows and the GROUP BY hurts efficiency. I have searched for a SQL/HiveQL operator that returns the number of times a JOIN ON condition is met for a particular row but I cannot find anything.

Another solution I considered is having a value increment each time the JOIN ON is satisfied, but I cannot think of a way to make this work.

Any helpful threads or solutions not involving aggregate functions would be amazing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually simpler to do this without the subquery:

```
SELECT s.name, s.ID, count(a.id) as absences
FROM Students LEFT JOIN 
     Absences a
     ON s.ID = a.ID
GROUP BY s.name, s.ID;
```

Comment: I was just showing an example of how to do it, but I am looking for a solution without a GROUP BY at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic count() to count joined Absences per student.ID:

```
SELECT s.name, s.ID, count(a.id) over(partition by s.ID) as absences
FROM Students s LEFT JOIN 
     Absences a
     ON s.ID = a.ID
;
```

If there is 1:M relationship between student and Absence then You will get duplication of rows after JOIN. In this case the GROUP BY is the right solution, and better do it in the subquery to aggregate Absence by student_ID before join, so join will receive less rows, like in your question example.